# how to enable the mwAlienExtension for MediaWiki VisualEditor

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

I'm trying to visualize `<section>` tags in MediaWiki's VisualEditor so that they can be easily modified and moved in a visual way - rather than having to utilize the source editor.

I have discovered a Wiki where the VisualEditor does just what I want: the `<section>` tag at the beginning of the page is graphically represented (I think using an "AlienExtension extension") and editable.

Here is the page with the tag:
[page with visual section tag](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Dictionary_of_Christian_Biography_and_Literature_(1911).djvu/161?veaction=edit)

However, I cannot figure out how to enable this capability in my own Wiki site. I'm using the following wiki/extension versions:

- MediaWiki 1.27.0
- LabeledSectionTransclusion (9212396) 23:33, 4 May 2016
- VisualEditor 0.1.0 (7445820) 20:23, 28 June 2016

Please help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you mean the Proofreading quality part? This is an extension that extends the VisualEditor. I don't know any extension that does this for the `<section>` tag.

Comment: were you able to look at the link that I provided? I don't think this visualization has to do with Proofreading. The beginning of the page shows a <section> tag under "Page body (to be transcluded)" that has a visual representation of a button with the symbol "<>" on it. when you click on that button, it is revealed as a <section> tag and can be edited. You can also drag the button to another location in the document. How is this accomplished?

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry, I haven't seen that :) This is the VE representation of the wikitext string `## Calandio or Calendio, bishop of Antioch ##`. For whatever reason (I suspect, that some extension hooks into the parser somehow), Parsoid (the parsing backend) recognizes the wikitext as an extension output. And because no data model handler is registered with VE to handle this data model, it uses the AlienExtension handler (which simply shows the content of the output). So, this doesn't have to do anything with the `<section>` tag, sorry.

Comment: E.g. open this link: https://en.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=Page:Dictionary_of_Christian_Biography_and_Literature_%281911%29.djvu/161&action=edit and click the little pencil at the top right of the editor to switch to VE. You'll see the text as as a numeric list.

Comment: Long time ago I was extending Visual Editor and discovered many interesting things which details that I can't remember now :) Only thing I can comment is that "AlienExtension" is not about extension, but built-in functionality of VE which represents all unknown entities/tags in page content. Usually Wikipedia uses modified version of VE, so only way to achieve something in your MW installation is to debug and investigate VE sources to extend it with your own solution.

Comment: Florian: it's just strange that these two links behave differently as far as representing the <section> tag: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Dictionary_of_Christian_Biography_and_Literature_(1911).djvu/161?veaction=edit and then https://en.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=Page:Dictionary_of_Christian_Biography_and_Literature_%281911%29.djvu/161&action=edit

Comment: @ConstantinScheder why would it be strange? One is the VisualEditor, the other is the normal editor.